# Does the HERE maps v7.2 API have an end of life planned?

Tags: routes, here-api

Is there an end of life data planned for the HERE maps v7.2 API?

We're looking at migration to v8.20, but there seem to be some features missing that we were using in the previous version.

Edit: We're using the routing API.  Some of the changes we've noted include:

- lack of support for "balanced" routing estimates.  Admittedly, the v7.2 api no longer seems work with the "shortest" routing.  We would like to return fastest, balanced, and shortest for comparison.
- v7.2 had more granular control to avoid, soft exclude, or strict exclude certain road features.  v8 seems to only implement "avoid"
- I haven't found a way to return lat/long for maneuvers taken on a trip, where the previous version returned those alongside the maneuver instructions.  The flexible polyline can be used to show the overall route, but doesn't include markers for each section of the trip (e.g. to designate a turn).
- there are some changes in the map metadata; the first example we pulled up introduced a roundabout where there is none, having a truck perform a 270 degree turn instead of simply turning right.

Comment: Would you be able to share what are some features that you were hoping to see before you migrate? I am DevRel at HERE and I'd be happy to pass this to our teams.

Comment: Also, Are you talking about HERE routing API? If not, can you specify exactly which API you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks - edited to include the missing information above.

Comment: There's currently **no planned end of life date** for HERE Routing API. A rough estimation would be towards the end of 2021, but that is subject to change. You are right pointing the missing areas from release notes, I shared your thoughts with the HERE Routing team :)

Comment: @PersistentPlants any update on the lifetime? As I cannot seem to find any info regarding the subject, anywhere...